# Shrinking ellipsoid in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am new to animations with matplotlib, and I am trying to animate a shrinking ellipsoid.

Specifically, I want to animate an ellipsoid that shrinks its axes proportionally. (Mathematically, I'm looking for a shrinking factor of e^(-t) multiplied to each axis, where t is time.)

I have made a function of time t that outputs a static ellipsoid with the code below:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def param_surface(t):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

    x = axis_a(4 * t / 50) * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
    y = axis_a(4 * t / 50) * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
    z = axis_b(4 * t / 50) * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

    return(ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride = 4, cstride = 4))
```

I have seen animations (such as the one here: https://pythonmatplotlibtips.blogspot.com/2018/11/animation-3d-surface-plot-funcanimation-matplotlib.html) that allow you to animate 3D plots in which z is defined as a function of x, y. However, in the case of the shrinking ellipsoid, I need to use spherical coordinates, which complicates things.

Can someone explain what to add to my code to go from static to the desired shrinking animation?

Comment: This is way too broad. What's the exact problem? Start by creating an ellipsoid which is static. Don't think about animations, until you can do that. Once that's done, parametrize the ellipsoid into a function. Only then think about how to call that function repeatedly with different parameters to create an animation.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I have created the static ellipsoid using spherical coordinates, I will add my code. I was unclear on this, but my main issue is that I do not understand the steps in creating an 3D animation, like the shrinking one I described. Thanks again.

Comment: You're still not at the point where to think about animations. So next step will be to parametrize the ellipsoid into a function, as said. Create a function that takes two radius parameters as input and outputs x,y,z accordingly.

Comment: I updated my code in the original post: is that what you are suggesting? I created a function that takes in the parameter t and outputs the time t ellipsoid. (The coefficients axis_a(t) and axis_b(t) are the axes functions, btw.)

Comment: Yeah but it would be better to have a function f(t) -> x,y,z; because at the end you want to have one single figure. So next you'll need a function that takes t as argument, calls f(t), removes any existing plot on the axes and creates a new surface plot. That function would be the one to call with `FuncAnimation`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to understand what you mean by outputting x, y, and z. Would that simply be return(x), return(y), return(z) in succession? And regarding removing the existing plot, can you explain how that can be done?

Comment: A python function as exactly one return statement, so `return x,y,z` would an option. Concerning removal, that is shown in the link you have in the question.